# How to deduce the template type in a class method and define a class field of that type?

Tags: c++, qt

The Qt framework provides a `QProperty<T>` template class which has a [onValueChanged](https://doc.qt.io/qt-6/qproperty.html#onValueChanged) template method.
Its signature is `template <typename Functor> QPropertyChangeHandler<Functor> QProperty::onValueChanged(Functor f)`. I need to deduce the return type of onValueChanged, so that the returned value can be stored as a class field. (std::any doesn't work because `QPropertyChangeHandler<Functor>` is not copy constructible). The returned type is `QPropertyChangeHandler<Functor>`, which is a template class that has a function-like type template parameter.

Here is the idea:

```cpp
class Foo {
  Foo(QProperty<uint> &property) {
    auto handler = property.onValueChanged(
        [this, &property] { /*some code*/ });
    using Handler = decltype(handler); // this is the type that needs to be deduced
    // m_handler = std::move(handler);
  }

  Handler m_handler; // cannot compile, Handler is not visiable in this scope
};
```

Here is a failed trial:

```cpp
class Foo {
  // try deducing the return type, don't know how to provide the same lambda signature
  using Handler = decltype(std::declval<QProperty<uint>>().onValueChanged([]{}));
  Handler m_handler;

  Foo(QProperty<uint> &property):
    m_handler{ // cannot compile, no matching constructor
        property.onValueChanged([this, &property] { /*some code*/ })
  }{
  }
};
```

Comment: *"I need to deduce the return type of onValueChanged..."* It will be automatically deduced from the function argument for parameter `f`.

Comment: *"don't know how to provide the same lambda signature..."* Lambdas don't have signature.

Comment: Note when you provide the template parameter explicitly, deduction won't happen.

Answer (score 0):

I was not aware that each lambda has a different type, even if all types of captures and parameters is the same. So the Functor type parameter should not be the type of any lambda, it could be a std::function.

```cpp
class Foo {
  using Functor = std::function<void(void)>;
  using Handler = QPropertyChangeHandler<Functor>;
  // or using Handler = decltype(std::declval<QProperty<uint>>().onValueChanged(std::declval<Functor>()));
  Handler m_handler;

  Foo(QProperty<uint> &property)
      : m_handler{
            property.onValueChanged<Functor>([this, &property] { /*some code*/ })} {}
};
```